# jquery submit calling function

Tags: jquery

jquery

```
function checkname(){
  //check name
}

function checkemail(){
  //check email
}

   function checkgender(){
       $("#gender-result").hide();
          if (undefined == $("input[name='gender']:checked", "#contact-form").val()) {
               $("#gender-result").html('gender requirements.').show();
               $('#gender-result').css('color', 'red');
               return false;          
          }
          return true;
     }

//jquery started
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#username").keyup(checkname);
   $("#gender").keyup(checkgender);
   $("#email").keyup(checkemail);
            $('#contact-form').submit(function(){
                checkgender();
                checkname();
                checkemail();
            }
        });
```

i am new to jquery , why is my submit wont active the function inside?? and if is good way to validation like this?

Comment: missing closing parenthesis on the next to last line.  change the single line of `}` to `})` and that should get you closer.

Comment: what is the structure of the those validation methods... does it return true/false

Comment: i edit one of my function , please check it out.

Comment: i got it ethorn thank~ careless me.

Comment: buddy you still missing the ')' parenthesis ..

Answer (score 1):

Your code does in fact call the validation functions, but it submits the form immediately after, so you don't know if anything validated. If you do it this way:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function () {
    if (!(checkgender() && checkname() && checkemail()){
        //tell the user they screwed up
        return false;
    }
});
```

When the form is submitted, it runs the validation functions. if they don't all return true, it does not submit the form, at which point you should inform the user they messed up. If the validation is successful, the form is submitted.

For your second question, yes this is a good way to do it, however, after your client side validation, you should always do additional server side validation.

...and also what @ethorn10 said, fix your missing parenthesis.

Comment: thank you , you spark my day , i was so worry i do wrong on client side validation.

Comment: Above code wont trigger your function, form would have been already submitted, Use must use event.preventDefault()

Comment: @AdarshGowdaKR you are incorrect, if the onsubmit function returns false, it prevents the form from being submitted. `event.preventDefault()` AND `return false;` are 2 different, valid ways of preventing form submission.https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @chiliNUT, Use must use event.preventDefault(), to prevent the default form.. Before entering your if condition, form values would have been submitted .. So to prevent that use must use event.preventDefault(), and return false is just validation thing , if that condition doesnt satisfied dont submit it.. Please read the article

Comment: @AdarshGowdaKR that is just not true at all. the form is not submitted until after the onsubmit function is executed. if the obsubmit function contains `event.preventDefault()` or `return false;` then the form is not submitted, otherwise, the form is submitted. But either way, the entire function will run first before the form is submitted.

Comment: @AdarshGowdaKR I think I see what you were getting at before: if you are using the native javascript onsubmit function, you can only use preventDefault(). For the jQuery onsubmit function, you can use either one.

Answer (score 0):

BY default '.submit function' will submit the form, to prevent that we must use 
 **event.preventDefault()**  [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bam7zg73/)

```
//jquery started
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#username").keyup(checkname);
   $("#gender").keyup(checkgender);
   $("#email").keyup(checkemail);
            $('#contact-form').submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); // preventing the default form submission
                checkgender();
                checkname();
                checkemail();
            })
        });
```

Comment: but the function wont active

Comment: Check out this link, https://jsfiddle.net/bam7zg73/ functions get activated upon submission , remaining validation you must write it..